# link_to for calling an action, instead of a button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to call an action with a link_to button without being redirected to another page(I don't want ajax). For you to have an idea, I'm trying to accomplish a sort "link button" in a search page. So, when the link is clicked, the page should be refreshed showing the list ordered as I tell it in the action.

If I do the following in my view, it will ask me for a template called as the action, and I don't want it:

```
<%=  link_to 'M&Aacute;S RELEVANTES', search_filter_relevance_path %>
```

My routes file looks like this:

```
map.search_filter_relevance "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search_filter_relevance'
```

**EDIT:**

If I change the above line to:

```
map.search_filter_relevance "/anuncios/search_filter_lowest_price", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search_filter_relevance'
```

it access to the action I want it to access, but I can't figure out a way to pass the collection of items I have in the view(it's a search result) to the action, so I can filter them.

And my controller looks like this(I haven't developed the functionality yet):

```
  def search_filter_relevance

  end
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should define what you'll render... an `action`, a `partial`, `nothing`?

```
def search_filter_relevance
   render :action => "some_action"
   # or
   render :partial => "some_partial"
   # or
   render :nothing => true
end
```

Something like that...

Maybe you could explain what you want this action to do exactly...

Comment: You know what I think the problem is...I have more than one entry at routes file that links to the same page("/anuncios/buscar"), and this is the order:

  map.search "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search'
  map.power_search "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'power_search'
  map.search_filter_relevance "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search_filter_relevance'

So, it's accesing "search" action when I click the link, and not "search_filter_relevance". How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think so :/ I believe the problem is that you don't have a `search_filter_relevance` view and you're not telling the action to render anything else...

Comment: I don't want a search_filter_relevance view. I just want the link to act as a button so when I click it, it sorts the list by a specific field. I want no rendering to any other page.

Comment: I believe you'll have to call the `list` (or any other name you have) action with some parameters. You can make this call inside `search_filter_relevance`, then the `list` view will be rendered.